# Redis: how to save to disk only 1 database?

Tags: redis

I'd like to install N redis server instances in master-slave mode.
By idea they should save to disk database-0 and do not save database-1 as security sensible data to keep it in memory only.

The same for the replication: all databses to replicate and each of slave nodes must save database-0 only but not database-1.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this. This level of fine-grained control requires multiple redis instances per persistence level and replication level.

This is perfectly fine and the recommended way to do this over redis, and in fact will give you better performance, as redis is single threaded.